# Windows 10 Вернуть доступ к ветке реестра

Tags: windows, реестр

Случайно вместо пользователя дал на запрет права группе  "все" для HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG и теперь не получается ни одно из ниже перечисленных:

1. Поменять владельца ветки
2. Добавить права любому пользователю

Как вернуть доступ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, вопрос решился
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

psexec64 -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe

Comment: Не забудьте отметить свой ответ решением.